# How to implement the pseudocode Swap A[i] and A[j]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, quicksort, pseudocode

I have this pseudocode to implement:

```
function partition (A, start, stop)
   Set pivot = A[stop] 
   Set i = start 
   for j in range(start, stop) do 
      if A[j] ≤ pivot then 
         Swap A[i] and A[j] 
         i++
      end if
   end for
   Swap A[i] and A[stop] 
   return i
end function
```

I am lost in line 6: "Swap A[i] and A[j]". How would that be written exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot easier in Python than most other languages, because Python has tuple packing and unpacking.

```
A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
```